# Как сделать в React динамическую стилизацию без styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

У меня есть компонент, который я стилизую динамически с помощью styled-components. Как мне сделать тоже самое не используя библиотеку styled-components? Использую лишь средства React.

```
import React from 'react'

import styled from 'styled-components'

const Paragraph = ({children, ...props}) => {

    const Text = styled.p`
        color:red;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:bold
    `
    return (
        <Text>привет как дела что делаешь</Text>
    )
}

export default Paragraph
```

Comment: Можно менять классы динамически, можно менять in-line стили

Comment: Да, инлайн стили отлично работают, но их использования хотелось бы избежать

Comment: Насчет классов, я передаю стили в пропсах, поэтому изменения классов не подходит